# calling an intent using basic card in dialog flow without using webhook

Tags: dialogflow-es, facebook-messenger

I'm newbie in Dialogflow and I have a project that is a chat bot. I use basic card for facebook messenger to display different options . My plan is, if the user selects one of those options another intent will be triggered where it will display it's information or response. I've tried to use text payload and enter a keyword (to call another intent) there but its not working. My question is, how would I call another intent when I clicked the button in basic card without using any codes?

My_sample_intent:
[image: Screen one]

S.InfoAng_nuno_art_foundation:
[image: screen two]

Comment: Please include the code that you tried.

Comment: good day sir @Dean! i didn't try any codes as of now. im working with the GUI environment of dialog flow console. so far, im working with the card for facebook messenger. i also used the input/output context wherein i put a name on the output context of the intent where it will display a card then when the button is clicked it will call the next intent and show its information/reply. i also used the same name in the input context of the next intent that supposed to be triggered through basic card.

Answer (score 0):

@aeri you can use suggestion chips after your card so that user can click on the chips and call the next intent

suppose your next intent has training phrases like
"add to cart"

so add a suggestion chip named as "add to cart" after your card display

Answer (score 0):

Inside the event section of the intent that you would like to be called give an event name :

```
<p style="color:red,">eventname </p>
```

In below code replace eventname for the key - "name", with the name you defined inside intent

```
{
  "followupEventInput": {
    "name": eventname,
     "languageCode": "en-US",
    "parameters": {
      "param-name": "param-value"
    }
  }
}
```

either you could include any parameters that would like to pass or remove parameters from your response and you can send that along with your payload.

Please see the [link](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/fulfillment-webhook#event).